# HTML - Navbar and Sidebar Not Fully Width

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

Hello I just want to make a full width of my sidebar and navbar, as of now they are not fully width why? Here is my code.

Here is the problem please see I added an image

[image]

my ***Side Bar***

Here is my Side Bar also this is not full

```
<ul class="sidebar navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
    <span>Dashboard</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="pagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
    <span>Pages</span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pagesDropdown">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header">Login Screens:</h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="login.html">Login</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="register.html">Register</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <h6 class="dropdown-header">Other Pages:</h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
    <span>Charts</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
    <span>Tables</span></a>
</li>
```

my ***Nav Bar***

Here is my Nav Bar, here the width is not full why

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">

  <a class="navbar-brand mr-1" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>

  <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm text-white order-1 order-sm-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar Search -->
  <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ml-auto mr-0 mr-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ml-md-0">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-fw"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Activity Log</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: If you add the class bootstrap utility class `w-100` to the offending div parent and add `mw-100` to the offending div, it might work to make the width 100%.

Comment: I've solved it with margin left on css :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that some of the classes that you are using must have some padding and you can confirm that by doing an inspect element.

You can do a work around through "margin-left" but its not always a good idea because it can bite in the back for bigger screens.